# Auto-merge merge conflicts of specific files in AzureDevops

Tags: azure-devops, git

We are using self-hosted Azure DevOps to manage our git repositories, and the "Pull Request Merge Conflict Extension" by Microsoft DevLabs. When submitting pull requests, there often are merge conflicts with our WPF resource files (simple XML). In 2 years, I've never encountered a situation where we would not like the merge to take the changes from both branches.

Now, is there any way to configure a default behavior for merge conflicts in certain files? The Visual Studio Marketplace page wasn't helpful to me.